# Movie man finds new boots, dances?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie maybe five to seven years ago post apocalyptic world I think, where a man finds a new pair of boots and then gets excited about it and dances. I can't remember what movie and recently got a new pair of boots myself the scene popped into my head, I looked through my movie library but nothing jumped out at me.

Comment: Probably not it, but looks....interesting?  [The FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_FP) about a post apocalyptic world where gang disputes are settled by dance-off.

Comment: No it is just one guy i don't remember if he had old boots or no boots but finds some better ones.

Comment: Probably not it unless your memory is playing up as its set in 1999 San Francisco but the 1996 Doctor Who TV movie has a sequence in which, pleased that he's got a pair of shoes which fit after this regeneration, the eighth Doctor (Paul McGann) does a little jigging dance.

Comment: There is a book named worn out boots by T. McDonald , I remember it fits in your description but I don’t know if a movie was made, It seems similar (except that is not a man , is a boy) to A boy and his dog, and this has a movie adaptation.

Comment: Didn't occur to me to ask, but animated or live action?  Some other helpful things to consider can be found in the [ask] list and even better in the [Good story-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/78394) lists.

Comment: What sort of dancing? Like Snoopy happy dance? Tap? Ballet? Hip-hop? And are they new boots, or new to him?

Comment: Just new to him he finds them somewhere, and just like a personal happy dance I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they were actually a pair of shoes or [combat boots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combat_boot) but this sounds an awful lot like a scene out of [***The book of Eli***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_of_Eli).

The protagonist has broken down shoes but finds a replacement set off a corpse hanging from a noose (Yuck).

References:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_of_Eli
https://www.amazon.com/gp/richpub/listmania/fullview/R2EYIPD4CJ4M87